# I am trying to edit a thought in my thoughts app. I am not able to update it

Tags: firebase, android-studio

```
package com.example.demo

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_update_thought.*

class UpdateThoughtActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private  lateinit var thoughtDocumentId: String
    lateinit var commentDocId: String
    lateinit var thoughtTxt: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_thought)
        thoughtDocumentId = intent.getStringExtra(THOUGHT_DOC_ID_EXTRA)!!
        commentDocId = intent.getStringExtra(COMMENT_USER_ID_EXTRA)!!
        thoughtTxt = intent.getStringExtra(COMMENT_TXT_EXTRA)!!
        updateThoughtTxt.setText(thoughtTxt)
    }
    fun updateThoughtClicked(view: View) {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(THOUGHTS_REF).document(thoughtDocumentId)
            .update(THOUGHT_TXT, updateThoughtTxt.text.toString())
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                hideKeyboard()
                finish()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e("Exception", "Could not update thought: ${exception.localizedMessage}")
            }
            }
    private fun hideKeyboard() {
        val inputManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        if (inputManager.isAcceptingText) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken,0)
        }
    }
    }


Here I am trying to update the thought. I am not able to update it.When I click on update button during runtime. I see this error.
```

E  Could not update thought: NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/fir-ee876/databases/(default)/documents/thoughts/null

```
I did for comments activity the same thing. It works fine. I am getting problem only for this.
Can you please help me with this?
```

I am trying to edit the thought and when I click on edit option it navigates to a new activity. In the new activity I want to update the thought and click on update button.When I click on that button the thought must be updated and must be displayed. When I tried this I am getting this error.

```
  E  Could not update thought: NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/fir-ee876/databases/(default)/documents/thoughts/null
```

Comment: Are you sure that a document exists at `.collection(THOUGHTS_REF).document(thoughtDocumentId)`?